# Flycheck Error Messages are cutoff by edge of window

Tags: flycheck, prelude, tooltip

I'm using Prelude Emacs. I could've sworn there was a simple option to allow the error tooltip to use multiple lines instead of 1, but I can't find it and my error messages get cut off by the window's edge. It's very frustrating to have to go list all flycheck errors just to see if it's something that matters or not.

I have found nothing digging through github or google, but maybe It's simpler than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option that you are looking for is `lsp-ui-sideline-diagnostics-max-lines`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured this out all that time ago, but I guess I forgot to type out the specific option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. As is often the case when nothing seems to be coming up for a search, remember to check all possible packages that control something. The issue was the LSP UI sideline's options.